# Sublime Text 2's "Goto Anything" (or instant search) for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, sublimetext, emacs24, dot-emacs, emacs-helm

I tried out [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) recently, and I found [Goto Anything](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36NIIgcrYzE) superbly useful for navigating source code ([Ctrl-P file@symbol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0OtfjgnoLA#t=1m00s) seems to work really well). Is there something similar for Emacs? Preferably something that just works, without a ton of custom elisp.

What I've tried so far:

1. I've seen [Helm](http://emacs-helm.github.com/helm/) and [Anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/Anything), <strike>but as far as I understand neither of them is capable of actual "instant" search</strike> (see edit below).
2. I've used [`multi-occur-in-matching-buffers`](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/07/20/searching-buffers-occur-mode/), but it too seems unable to satisfy the "instant" criterion.
3. [`imenu`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode) / [`idomenu`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/idomenu.el) works well for single files, but doesn't work across files.

I currently use #2 and #3 together, as a poor substitute for Goto Anything.

If not an exact clone of Goto Anything, then I could make do with a naive instant search solution (one that searches for a given string across all open buffers and displays results dynamically). So that's acceptable too.

I use Emacs 24.2, so any v24-only elisp is also fine.

**EDIT**: I gave Helm another shot, at [event_jr's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726601/sublime-text-2s-goto-anything-or-instant-search-for-emacs#14731718), and I found that it *does* support instant searching across all open buffers. `helm-multi-occur` + `helm-follow-mode` comes surprisingly close to meeting my needs, the only minor issues being (at the risk of sounding nit-picky):

- <strike>I haven't found a way to turn on `helm-follow-mode` *automatically* when I run `helm-multi-occur`. I have to invoke it manually with `C-c C-f`. Anyone care to take a shot at this with a snippet of elisp?</strike> (see edit #2 below)
- it isn't "intelligent" like ST2's Goto Anything (i.e., it doesn't understand "symbols" in source code, like Goto Anything does).

**EDIT #2**: Now I've got most of Goto Anything, thanks to [event_jr's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726601/sublime-text-2s-goto-anything-or-instant-search-for-emacs#14731718) (and of course, thanks to Helm's creator, [Thierry Volpiatto](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto)). I recommend it heartily to anyone looking for a similar feature. Below is the elisp I'm currently using:

```lisp
;; instant recursive grep on a directory with helm
(defun instant-rgrep-using-helm ()
  "Recursive grep in a directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((helm-after-initialize-hook #'helm-follow-mode))
    (helm-do-grep)))


;; instant search across all buffers with helm
(defun instant-search-using-helm ()
  "Multi-occur in all buffers backed by files."
  (interactive)
  (let ((helm-after-initialize-hook #'helm-follow-mode))
    (helm-multi-occur
     (delq nil
           (mapcar (lambda (b)
                     (when (buffer-file-name b) (buffer-name b)))
                   (buffer-list))))))

;; set keybindings
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-s") 'instant-search-using-helm)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-S-s") 'helm-resume)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-g") 'instant-rgrep-using-helm)
```

Comment: This would probably be a better question for superuser.com

Comment: No, questions about Emacs in the context of programming are 100% in scope of SO

Comment: Why not just stick with sublime?

Comment: @event_jr I'm not going to switch from Emacs to Sublime Text just because it doesn't have Goto Anything. I'll gain one thing and lose a million if I do that :)

Comment: @VickyChijwani What are some killer features of Emacs missing in ST2?

Comment: @event_jr It's not about specific "killer features". In fact, Emacs doesn't even _have_ a fixed set of "features". It's about the editor in general. I love how easy it is to modify _every last shred of Emacs_. The infinite customizability constantly compounds and pays off. Every little customization I make brings it closer to my mental image of the "ideal" editor. In a sense, _that is Emacs' **real** killer feature_.

If I were using ST2, on the other hand, my productivity would quickly saturate to the maximum level possible with it.

Comment: Helm and Anything together? Helm is basically a continuation of the now defunct Anything project.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov I meant I've tried out Anything and Helm independently, at different points of time.

Comment: Your comment about "symbols", did you mean method definitions a la imenu?

Comment: Yes, those, and perhaps other definitions too if possible (constants, etc).

Comment: Emacs supports symbols directly through its regular expression engine.  You use `\_<` to mark anchor to beginning to a symbol and `\_>` to anchor to the end.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Just use helm.

It is perhaps more configuration than you asked for, but once you get it
configured how you like, it should be quite comfortable.  Very much like Emacs
;).

And you should file a bug with Thierry for getting some more newbie friendly
defaults.  He is quite responsive with issues.

#### helm-multi-occur

Primarily multi-buffer interactive "occur" is provided through
`helm-multi-occur`.  If you execute the command, you'll notice that you have
to pick some buffers first (use <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> to select from the list,
<kbd>M-SPC</kbd> to select all).  Then you can enter your query at the next
prompt.  It's easy to make your own version that skips the buffer selection
like so:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "helm-regexp"
    '(setq helm-source-moccur
           (helm-make-source "Moccur"
               'helm-source-multi-occur :follow 1)))

(defun my-helm-multi-all ()
  "multi-occur in all buffers backed by files."
  (interactive)
  (helm-multi-occur
   (delq nil
         (mapcar (lambda (b)
                   (when (buffer-file-name b) (buffer-name b)))
                 (buffer-list)))))
```

#### helm-buffers-list

Often you don't care about the exact occurrences of the query string, but want a
list of all buffers that contain it.

`helm-buffers-list` has some tricks up its sleeve.  The first symbol you
specify is filtering by major-mode, and you can use the "@" prefix to narrow
the list to buffers that contain a string.

To wit, "ruby @prompt" will show you a list of buffers whose major-mode
contains "ruby" and whose contents contains "prompt".  Or you can just use "@prompt" to show all buffers that contain "prompt".

---

Powerful and comfortable once you get used to it.

---

**EDIT** modified `my-helm-multi-all` to enable helm-follow-mode.

**EDIT 2** update `helm-follow-mode` code to reflect helm changes.

**EDIT 3** updated again to reflect [helm changes](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/623)

Comment: This is great. I tried Helm again, at your suggestion, and I think `my-helm-multi-all` + `helm-follow-mode` (accessed via `C-c C-f` in a Helm buffer) comes pretty close to what I want. So thank you for that, firstly. Now the only major issue is that I have to manually turn on `helm-follow-mode` when I run `my-helm-multi-all`; is there a way to have it turn on automatically? (note that Helm doesn't seem to have a `helm-mode-hook`, so that approach won't work).

Comment: Can this (i.e., turning on `helm-follow-mode` automatically in Helm buffers) be done using `defadvice` on `helm-mode` or `helm-multi-occur`?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to do it with a provided hook.  `defadvice` is akin to a chainsaw, it's rarely necessary to solve your problems.

Comment: Nice, this gives me like 95% of what I wanted. Thank you so much. It'd be silly to pursue this any longer for that _one_ remaining annoyance. I'm accepting your answer. And I think I should learn some elisp myself :)

Comment: Hi. I tried this and i get `Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`. I'm using Emacs 24.

Comment: thanks for great info. I'm big fan of source insight. helm + gtags help me with quick source code browsing.

Comment: It seems as though a recent update to helm has broken this again.

Comment: Indeed.  @nispio I've fixed up the code as per your rejected edit.

Comment: It seems that `@foo` in `helm-buffers-list` searches the name of the buffer for that text, not the contents. Perhaps this has changed, or there's a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using `helm-buffers-list`?

Answer (score 7):

Emacs has [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) satisfy your need:

- jump to a file in project
- multi-occur in project buffers

Comment: It can also jump to tests and project buffers, grep in projects, replace in projects, regenerate the etags table and other cool stuff. Projectile also has a helm backend.

Comment: As I said in my question, I've used `multi-occur` and it doesn't do *instant searching* ("instant" in the sense of "Google Instant"). With `multi-occur`, you have to type in your entire query, press `RET`, and only then you get to see the results. Also, if you need to change your search query you have to run `multi-occur` again with your new search term. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Vicky: FWIW, I had no idea what "instant searching" was supposed to mean until you mentioned "Google Instant" -- and only then after I Googled the phrase "Google Instant" to see what *that* was. The expression "instant searching" is *extremely* vague unless you already know what Google means by it. I would suggest something like "dynamic search results" would be a much clearer description.

Comment: @phils that is exactly why I linked to videos demonstrating the feature, right in my question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36NIIgcrYzE and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0OtfjgnoLA#t=1m00s

Answer (score 1):

1. Heml is far from the fuzzy searching of ST3.
2. [Fiplr](https://github.com/d11wtq/fiplr) looks promising but doesn't work on my laptop (see first issue on the github)
3. [Simp.el](https://github.com/re5et/simp) looks like Fiplr but doesn't work either on my end.
4. [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) works for me! Here's your solution!

I used also ido-mode and flx-ido for the fuzzy searching,

and for the vertical way of displaying results I use this in my .emacs:

```
;; Display ido results vertically, rather than horizontally
(setq ido-decorations (quote ("\n-> " "" "\n   " "\n   ..." "[" "]" " [No match]" " [Matched]" " [Not readable]" " [Too big]" " [Confirm]")))
(defun ido-disable-line-truncation () (set (make-local-variable 'truncate-lines) nil))
(add-hook 'ido-minibuffer-setup-hook 'ido-disable-line-truncation)
(defun ido-define-keys () ;; C-n/p is more intuitive in vertical layout
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-n") 'ido-next-match)
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-p") 'ido-prev-match))
(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-define-keys)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I provided answers that don't work for me but might work for others.

Comment: I assume you're using flx for fuzzy search within projectile?

Comment: more like ido + flx-ido

Answer (score 0):

**[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles)** offers some features that are similar to what it seems you are looking for.

1. `C-x b` and `C-x C-f`, to choose buffers or files, allow multi-completion: you can type a pattern to match the buffer/file name and/or a pattern to [match content](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#SecondExampleMultiCompletion) in the [buffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input)/[file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#MatchFileContent). Candidates are filtered [incrementally](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion#CompletionsIcompletion) as you type (what you call "instant" is what Emacs calls "incremental").  You can refine either or both search patterns [progressively](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion), narrowing the choices in different ways.  You can visit any number of buffers/files that match, at the same time.  You can also use the same method to search the marked files in Dired: `C-F`.
2. `C-c` `` ` ``([`icicle-search`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview)) incrementally searches across multiple buffers or files.  Again, progressive refinement etc.

The main difference between #1 and #2 is this:

- For #1, you just want to find matching buffers or files.  You don't care immediately about finding particular occurrences --- any match suffices.
- For #2, you provide the buffers or files to search, and you want to navigate among search hits.

You can also use #1 to locate the buffers and files you want, then search their contents: The content-matching pattern you last used is available as the search pattern for Isearch (`C-s`).

Answer (score 0):

for emacs I customize and modify this solution (for use install helm):

```
(defun helm-occur-from-point (initial-value)
  "Invoke `helm-occur' from point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((input initial-value)
        (bufs (list (buffer-name (current-buffer)))))
    ;; (isearch-exit)
    (helm-occur-init-source)
    (helm-attrset 'moccur-buffers bufs helm-source-occur)
    (helm-set-local-variable 'helm-multi-occur-buffer-list bufs)
    (helm-set-local-variable
     'helm-multi-occur-buffer-tick
     (cl-loop for b in bufs
              collect (buffer-chars-modified-tick (get-buffer b))))
    (helm :sources 'helm-source-occur
          :buffer "*helm occur*"
          :history 'helm-grep-history
          :input input
          :truncate-lines t)))

(defun get-point-text ()
    "Get 'interesting' text at point; either word, or region"
    (if mark-active
        (buffer-substring (mark) (point))
      (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
  (defun helm-occur-1 (initial-value)
    "Preconfigured helm for Occur with initial input."
    (helm-occur-from-point initial-value))
  (defun bk-helm-occur ()
    "Invoke helm-occur with initial input configured from text at point"
    (interactive)
    (helm-occur-1 (get-point-text)))
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-s-o") 'bk-helm-occur)
```

primary it based on 
@see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6872508 but on last helm versions not work but fixed with my changes (just copy/paste from some internal helm modules)